# Repository of virus-infected computer files

Tags: data-request, software, security

I have set up an Alfresco document management server and an extension that claims to block virus-infected documents from being uploaded to the server.

Now I want to test it with files infected with a variety of commonly found viruses.
Is there a freely reusable repository of such files?

- Of course .exe viruses should be present, but also .doc files or .pdf files that are specially-crafted to trigger privilege escalation and attacks in Word or Acrobat, for instance.
- For obvious reason, the files should be distributed within an archive file.
- As recent and representative as possible.

Answer (score 2):

1. [This discussion is old](http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/want-to-download-some-virus-files-to-test-out-my-anti-virus-wares-317/) but it might still help you. [It points to this page on EICAR](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) which is still up. [Another site](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/general/459) to grab the EICAR test file.

Comment: The EICAR page says: "it is not a virus, and does not include any fragments of viral code. Most products react to it as if it were a virus"

Comment: @Nicolas It would only prove that your extension catches EICAR, and indeed not all the other infection vectors. There are two things that you can look at that would prove *the opposite*, i.e. don't rely on your extension: 1) It does not catch EICAR 2) It does not have regular virus signature updates

Comment: "it is not a virus, and does not include any fragments of viral code. Most products react to it as if it were a virus". That just means it's not a true virus intent on wreaking havoc on your PC, nor does it replicate, *but it has code that looks like a virus*. It still should be ID'd as a virus by a virus scanner. Thus my suggestion as a starting point, since a Google search yielded nothing else.